# Android Hotspot shown as unidentified network and no internet access after using 40-35 minutes

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, android, hotspot

I use an Android mobile hotspot on my Windows 7 PC.

After using it for 15-30 minutes the connection drops and my hotspot shown as unidentified network and no internet access on the PC after.

data saver is also off on my mobile

To get a connection again I have to turn of the hotspot and turn on again,
are there any solutions to fix this?

Comment: upgrade to windows 10.

Comment: Try a USB WiFi adapter on your Windows PC and test again if it drops or not. Does it happen with any other client if you have one?

Comment: im using a wifi adapter,   it shows unidentified network after 45 minutes and no internet access after

Answer (score 0):

Check first the android mobile hotspot settings if there is any data limitations and turn it off.

Comment: no there are no data saver or data limitations on

Answer (score 0):

I once experienced this same issue some time ago.
It usually happens when you have changed your PC's network adapter settings.
You can either try using USB Tethering option from your android phone. Or you can reset your PC's network adapter settings